# Unable to get selected text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify code provided at 'http://jsfiddle.net/vivin/RjqUf/'(not adding code to keep question short and less confusing) to get a line or a word of pdf selected by user. I have added following javascript at the end of javascript window leaving everything else as it is.

```
$(".textLayer").mouseup(function() {
    var selectedText;
  // IE version
  if (document.selection != undefined)
  {
    $(this).focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  // Mozilla version
  else if ($(this).selectionStart != undefined)
  {
    var startPos = $(this).selectionStart;
    var endPos = $(this).selectionEnd;
    selectedText = $(this).value.substring(startPos, endPos)
  }
    alert(selectedText );
});
```

Could you guys please tell me whats wrong?

Comment: What in the....... there are too many lines in the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does jQuery really have a `selectionStart` property?

Put aside jQuery, for “Mozilla version” you should be using, for example, standard `window.getSelection().toString()`.

Comment: ..Thank you! this one worked. I took above piece of code from another stackoverflow answer. (planning to add that link but couldn't find it right now)